# preg_replace on 'æøå' not working as expected

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to parse a CSV file before importing the data.. I want to exclude all unwanted characters, but can't make `æøå` work in `preg_replace`

All unwanted characters is removed including `æøåÆØÅ`

Input file charset: `ISO 8859-1`
PHP file charset: `UTF-8`

### Input

```
"EI25";"EU køb";"16640";"25";"100";"NET";"16630"
```

### Code

```
$contents = file_get_contents('./vatcode.csv');
$contents = preg_replace("/[^A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå0-9_\s\"';,\/\.\+\-\\\\]/", '', $contents);
```

### Output

```
"EI25";"EU kb";"16640";"25";"100";"NET";"16630"
```

Comment: What charset is the file?

Comment: sorry.. forgot to tell.. have updated question

Comment: Does it work with the `u` modifier?

Comment: With `u` modifier the output is empty

Comment: works perfectly for me with PHP 5.4.16. which PHP version are you using? i would be getter if you add expected output also (otherwise bit confusing)

Comment: Found out that is because the PHP file is encoded with UTF-8 :D

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this kind of encoding problems, you can use the `\p{Latin}` instead of hardcoding letters one by one:

```
$contents = preg_replace('~[^\p{Latin}0-9_\s"\';,\\\/.+-]+~u', '', $contents);
```

Maybe one of these classes can be helpful too (from [PCRE documentation](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt)):

```
P     Punctuation
Pc    Connector punctuation
Pd    Dash punctuation
Pe    Close punctuation
Pf    Final punctuation
Pi    Initial punctuation
Po    Other punctuation
Ps    Open punctuation
```

Answer (score 1):

This will delete all special characters except from SPACE TO DEL 
see this table [ascii table](http://www.bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ascii.html)

```
$contents = file_get_contents('./vatcode.csv');
$contents = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $contents);
echo($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it's because the PHP file is encoded with `UTF-8`